# SQL - how can I get a number of admins in the same team

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a team_member table with simplified structure like this

```
team_member_id | team_id | role
1              | 1       | ADMIN
2              | 1       | USER 
3              | 2       | ADMIN
4              | 2       | ADMIN
```

So the last two guys are admins on the same team. I need to build SQL query that will tell me how many teams there are with more than one admin per team.

Comment: try groupby  and use having  with count >1

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(team_id) -- Count Of Team_id Having More Than One ADMIN
FROM (
SELECT team_id,COUNT(*) -- COUNT ADMIN PER Team_id
FROM Table1
WHERE role='ADMIN'
GROUP BY team_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) AS T1
```

**Live Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/978f4/15

Comment: All answers are good, I had an inkling that I would have to use COUNT and GROUP BY but it would take me a while to fin out HAVING. It's been a long time since I used SQL. Thanks for the SQLFiddle link  - I will use it as a playground.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(`role`) 
FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE `role` = 'Admin' 
GROUP BY `team_id`
HAVING COUNT(`role`) > 1
```

Comment: You missed the "more than one admin per team" part.

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks for noting that

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(Role),
        Team_id

FROM MyTable

WHERE Role = 'Admin'

GROUP BY Team_id

HAVING COUNT(Role) > 1
```